# Android Reference Methods in Custom View from Activity

Tags: android

I have a Custom View which is stored in a XML Layout. The XML Layout is the View for my Activity. I am able to reference to the Custom View inside the XML Layout from my Activity, just as you would for any Android Widget. I can then get the onTouch listener which works fine. What I want to be able to do is reference to a method inside my Custom View which will enable me to draw on the Canvas. I have tied by Using the following code but have had no success. Any help would be much appreciated. PS My code does much more than this, I have just listed what I think is most necessary.

```
public class DrawView extends View {

         public Canvas;
         public Paint textPaint = new Paint()

         public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
         super.DrawView(context attributeSet)
         textPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text));
         }

         @Override
         onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
             mCanvas = canvas;
         }

         public void drawText() {
             mCanvas.drawText("text", 100, 100, textPaint);
         }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView mDrawView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sch_main);

        //Get Handlers To DrawView
        mDrawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw);

        //Get onTouch from DrawView
        mDrawView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                }
                else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                }
                else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    mDrawView.drawText();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <example.DrawLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/draw"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hold on to the `Canvas` passed to `onDraw` and paint whenever you like, you can only draw on the canvas when `onDraw` is called.

You should rethink the design of `DrawView`: have fields storing data about what should be drawn, allow methods to change these fields and do the actual drawing inside `onDraw` based on those fields. In your simple case, you could store a `boolean` field to indicate if the text should be drawn (e.g. `isTextVisible`), have a method to set it to `true` and draw it inside `onDraw` if the field value is `true`.

You can choose to make your methods force a redraw by calling `invalidate()`, so the changes are made effective immediately.